# Is VS Code Server usage a service?

Tags: eula, service

According to the [Common questions section](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/vscode-server#_common-questions) VS Code Server cannot be run as a service.
If I preinstall and configure a web instance for each developer, would that be a kind of unpaid “service”?

Comment: Weird. "Service" could mean one of several things there. I looked at the license to see if they define it explicitly, and not only is there no such definition but I also did not see anything that specifies that it cannot be run as a service.  I suppose they mean "installed as a Windows service or similar," but unless they specify it's difficult to say.  The arrangement you describe sounds to me like the answer to the previous FAQ, however, which says "an instance of the server is designed to be accessed by a single user."

Comment: @phoog They say "hosting it as a service", which makes me think they're not referring to the technical term "Windows service", but instead "business service". (Regardless of if a Windows service was or was not used to provide such a business service.)

Comment: @DanGetz true.  Though when u went to confirm that I had indeed overlooked the word "hosting," I got a 503 "service is unavailable" error, how ironic.  And once that went away, I see that in "scope of license" they do say that you cannot (among other things) "host" the software, the other things on the list including "share, publish, rent, or lease," so indeed that makes the most sense.

Comment: Hunter86bg: who are the developers referred to by "each developer"?

Comment: @phoog , the devs are me and my colleagues from the team.

Comment: What team? How are you organized?  Who owns the computer where you would preinstall and configure a web instance for each developer?

Comment: @phoog,I don’t think that the first 2 questions even matter. Just a team of devs in a company sharing company server.

Comment: @phoog The license, in 1(a), grants rights to "install, use and/or deploy any number of copies of the software on computer devices within your internal corporate network to design, develop and test your applications". The license does not grant rights for using the software outside your internal corporate network.